# Odoo: External ID not found in the system: stock.view_picking_out_form

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'am using Odoo 8.0 and I want to install the "picking_invoice_rel" module. But when I click on the "install" button, I get the following error:

```
OpenERP Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 500, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 517, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 283, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 113, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 280, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 733, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 376, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 237, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 450, in button_immediate_install
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 237, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 498, in _button_immediate_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 324, in new
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 358, in load_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 263, in load_marked_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 182, in load_module_graph
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 899, in convert_file
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 985, in convert_xml_import
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 851, in parse
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 756, in _tag_record
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 832, in id_get
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 841, in model_id_get
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 237, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py", line 951, in get_object_reference
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 237, in wrapper
  File "<string>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\.\openerp\tools\cache.py", line 71, in lookup
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py", line 909, in xmlid_lookup
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: stock.view_picking_out_form" while parsing file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Odoo%208.0/server/openerp/addons/picking_invoice_rel/picking_view.xml:18, near
<record id="view_picking_out_invoice_rel_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">picking.out.invoice.rel.form</field>
      <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
      <field name="type">form</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_out_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <page string="Notes" position="after">
          <page string="Invoices" groups="picking_invoice_rel.group">
            <field name="invoice_ids" colspan="4" nolabel="1"/>
          </page>
        </page>
      </field>
    </record>
```

Should I add the view_picking_out_form's definition in the addons\stock\stock.py or do I miss some modules?
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

ODOO 8 stock_view.xml doesn't have that id. so you are using openerp 7 module, that is the problem

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: I fixed that by downloading the appropriate module from this list [link](http://pragtech.co.in/labs/downloads/openerp-7-modules-2/modules-page-1.html)